# Kendo ui autocomplete with WCF json not working

Tags: wcf, autocomplete, kendo-ui

I’, using Kendo ui autocomplete control un a Project. The autocomplete gets the data from a WCF service returning data in JSON format.
In the html page I put this code:

```
$("#txtAutocomplete").kendoAutoComplete({
            filter: "contains",
            minLength: 3,
            dataSource: {
                type: "json",
                serverFiltering: true,
                serverPaging: true,
                pageSize: 20,
                transport: {
                    read: "http://localhost:52054/MyService.svc/Autocomplete"
                }
            }
        });
```

The WCF service can be called like:

```
http://localhost:52054/MyService.svc/Autocomplete/anyword
```

And it responds with an json file like this:

```
["abc1","abc2","abc3"]
```

But the autocomplete don’t Works, and I get multiple syntax errors in jquery.min.js

Any suggestion?
Thanks for your time!

Comment: Which syntax errors? Are you including needed KendoUI JavaScript files?

Comment: I included all the needed files. The autocomplete Works with a memory array.
The syntax errors was in jquery.min.js

Comment: I've tested with my own version of your service and it worked. Please, provide (exact) additional information on jQuery errors.

Comment: Seems that there is a problem with the error... or you mean that it actually is `-`

Comment: "Exception in line 3, column 25173 in http://localhost:52054/Scripts/jquery.min.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript Runtime Error JavaScript: SyntaxError

Comment: I put a list, instead a service, and the autocomplete Works, **but I have the same exception in every keystroke**, then I supouse that the JavaScript error is no the guilty! :)

Comment: Would be possible to share the version with the list? Is it a long HTML?

Comment: I use a simple function thats returns a simple array of strings, no database Access. But when debug, don't stop in the service call. It seems that no call to the service!